# WinForms Exception handling

Tags: c#, error-handling, exception

I got a method that is filling dataset from db which looks like more or less like this:

```
private DataSet GetData(string query)
{
    try
    {
        //do some stuff to populate dataset
        return dataset;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There was a database error. Please contact administrator.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        LogExceptionToFile(ex); //to log whole exception stack trace, etc.
    }
    finally
    {
        //cleanup
    }
}

//calling methods:
GetData(query);
OtherMethod1(); //this method shows message box of success
```

When I have that piece of code in case of exception I got my user friendly message box and then `OtherMethod1()` is called and it shows success message box. I would like to stop if in `GetData()` there is an error. When I add `throw;` to this catch block after my message box, there is another message box shown than unhandled exception was thrown. I would like to avoid this second message box to be shown if I have friendly message provided.

Comment: If you're adding a `throw` in your `GetData()` method, you need a try/catch around the method to actually catch the exception. Otherwise, you'll need some variable to keep track of success/failure in `GetData`, then act accordingly by whether there was an exception or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can return a value indicating success:

```
private bool TryGetData(string query, out DataSet dataSet)
{
    try
    {
        dataSet = ...;
        //do some stuff to populate dataset
        return true;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There was a database error. Please contact administrator.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        LogExceptionToFile(ex); //to log whole exception stack trace, etc.
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        //cleanup
    }
}

//calling methods:
DataSet ds;
if (TryGetData(query, out ds))
{
   OtherMethod1(); 
}
else
{
   //error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your predicament correctly, you can rethrow and handle the (currently unhandled) exception like so:

```
private DataSet GetData(string query)
{
    try
    {
        //do some stuff to populate dataset
        return dataset;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There was a database error. Please contact administrator.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        LogExceptionToFile(ex); //to log whole exception stack trace, etc.

        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        //cleanup
    }
}


//calling methods:
try
{
    GetData(query);
    OtherMethod1(); //this method shows message box of success
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Do whatever you need to do here, if anything.
}
```

Now, this certainly isn't the only way to do this, I'm only showing you how to do what it sounds like you were attempting. Some of these other answers are great as well, and may better suit your particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you could use a callback.

[Here's a link on returning multiple values](http://www.dotnetperls.com/multiple-return-values)

Get your `GetData()` method to return multiple values using a callback. You can then set, let's say a `success` bool from the `callBack`'s value(s) given by the `GetData()` method.

Then further on in your calling code, only run your `OtherMethod()` if the `success` bool is `true`.

You could even return the `ex` Exception as part of the callback, and use one single piece of code to show a dialog; whether it was a success or failure, and show the exception in it if so.

Example:

```
private DataSet GetData(string query, Action<bool> callBack)
{
    bool successful = false; // This will be returned in the callback.
    DataSet returnValue; // This will be the dataset stuff.
    try
    {
        //do some stuff to populate dataset
        returnValue = ???; // Populate your return value , but don't return yet;
        successful = true; // This will indicate success.
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There was a database error. Please contact administrator.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        LogExceptionToFile(ex); //to log whole exception stack trace, etc.
    }
    finally
    {
        //cleanup

        if (callBack != null) // Send the callback with the boolean of successful.
        {
            callBack(successful);
        }

        return returnValue; // Now return your DataSet.
    }
}

bool success = false; // Use this to determine if GetData was successful.
//calling methods:
GetData(query, (s) => success = s);

if (success)
{
    OtherMethod1(); //this method shows message box of success
}
else
{
    // Do something else, or show your failure message box.
}
```

Much cleaner, that way.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply return `null` in case of an error. (Albeit that the use of `null` might be discouraged depending on who you talk to or what the coding guidelines in your company or project might be.)

```
private DataSet GetData(string query)
{
    try
    {
        //do some stuff to populate dataset
        return dataset;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There was a database error. Please contact administrator.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        LogExceptionToFile(ex); //to log whole exception stack trace, etc.
    }
    finally
    {
        //cleanup
    }

    return null;
}

//calling methods:
var result = GetData(query);
if (result != null) 
    OtherMethod1(); //this method shows message box of success
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `throw;` to `catch` in `GetData()`:

```
private DataSet GetData(string query)
{
    try
    {
        //do some stuff to populate dataset
        return dataset;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There was a database error. Please contact administrator.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        LogExceptionToFile(ex); //to log whole exception stack trace, etc.
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        //cleanup
    }
}
```

and then do this:

```
try
{
  GetData(query);
  OtherMethod1();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // do something to ex if needed
}
```

This way you won't get the second message box and can handle the exception again if needed.